# One symfony form block is displayed by default, but I need zero blocks

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I built a new form and by default there's one form-block displayed in the collection of blocks.

I want to have zero form-blocks in this collection by default.

What parameter is responsible for the number of form-blocks/entries in the collection by default?

I've attached the `buildForm` function for the collection in my `ClassType.php` file.

```php
$builder
// [..]
  ->add(
    'images',
    CollectionType::class,
    [
      'entry_type'     => StoAttachmentType::class,
      'by_reference'   => false,
      'allow_add'      => !$options['disabled'],
      'allow_delete'   => !$options['disabled'],
      'prototype_name' => '__attachments__',
        'disabled'       => $options['disabled'],
        'attr'           => [
          'class'               => 'collection',
          'data-prototype-name' => '__attachments__',
          'data-add'            => $options['disabled'] ? '0' : '1',
          'data-allow-delete'   => $options['disabled'] ? '0' : '1',
          'data-links-template' => 'collection',
          'data-file-preview'   => '1',
          'data-help'           => 'Sto.images.help'
        ],
        'label'          => 'Sto.images',
        'entry_options'  => [
        'disabled' => $options['disabled'],
        'multiple' => true,
        'withMain' => true
      ],
    ]
  )
```

StoAttachmentType consist of three fields. The first one is required => True. Others fields is required => False.
Problem was resolved by overwriting class, but it's too much code. Is there any easier way?

Comment: i would assume it's `required` set to false, which *might* take the one away as well... but I'm not certain here... on edit however, existing entries will be displayed still. the only way to be certain is to override the form theme

Comment: If I understood you correctly setRendered might help {% do form.x.setRendered %}